# How to make a function to use it in many controllers?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to create a function to use it in most of the controllers for a table where you need to authenticate as an Administrator (Administrador in spanish). This is the .js with the controller described:

```
import {Convocatoria} from '../models/Convocatoria.js';
import {Proyecto} from '../models/Proyecto.js'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

export const createConvocatoria = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const bearerHeader = await req.headers['authorization'];
        const bearer = bearerHeader.split(" ");
        const token = bearer[1];
        if(!token) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                auth: false,
                message: 'No se ha proporcionado token'
            })
        }
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "mi_clave_secreta");
        if(decoded.rol === "Administrador"){
            const {identificador_institucional, pauta_evaluacion, estado_convocatoria, tipo_revision} = req.body
            const newConvocatoria = await Convocatoria.create({
            identificador_institucional, 
            pauta_evaluacion, 
            estado_convocatoria, 
            tipo_revision
        })
        res.json(newConvocatoria);
        } else {
            res.status(403).json({
                message: 'Prohibido'
            })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({message: error.message});
    }
}
```

And everything except the content of `if(decoded.rol === "Administrador)` and the `res.json(newConvocatoria)` I want to reuse it on another controller like updateConvocatoria. Still have some issues learning Node.js, since this is my first API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use middleware functions, i think  is what you need to implement.

//controllers where you dont want to check token

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  //check token
  next();
});
```

//controllers where you want to check token